# CUDA copysign() function not found in __device__ function (MSVC)

Tags: c++, cuda

I want to use the CUDA math API function `__device__ float copysignf(float x, float y)` (see the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1gf624240731f96c35e2bbf9aaa9217ad6)) from withing a `__device__` function. I included `math.h` and I am using the Visual Studio 2012 tool chain. `copysignf()` is not defined there, but `_copysignf()` is (note the underscore). I guess this could cause the issue - compiling results in an error:

`Error  1   error : calling a __host__ function("_copysignf") from a __global__ function("test_kernel") is not allowed  C:\cuda.cu(152) (col. 10)`

How can I use the CUDA `copysignf()` function from within Visual Studio?

Note: I double-checked for template argument mismatches, both arguments are of `float` type.

Comment: Don't use `_copysignf()`.  What happens if you use `copysignf()`?

Comment: `copysignf()` works indeed, thank you! I didn't try it because IntelliSense complains about it being undefined. Should have known better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the error described in the question because `_copysignf()` is in fact a host function, and has no device (i.e. CUDA) counterpart.

Just use the functions described in the documentation you linked.  You won't necessarily find these all defined in the `math.h` that ships with Visual Studio, but that is not the determinant of what will work in CUDA device code.

The intellisense indication is a separate issue, and many folks have worked around it to some degree.  Just search on SO for "CUDA red underline" and you'll find many suggestions.  But an intellisense indication in CUDA code does not necessarily indicate a problem.

Comment: CUDA basically supports all math function defined by ANSI C99 (and some additional ones). While it generally relies on the host's math.h header file to supply the necessary function prototypes, it supplies its own prototypes for functions whose prototypes are not in math.h. You can find these prototypes in the CUDA supplied file math_functions.h.